# What is my wrong argument or invalid property assignment?

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I am trying to filter the Carrier sheet using the userform / comboboxes.  I am receiving an error on the line " Sheets("Carrier").range.AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=ComboBoxA.value". "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

I jhave deleted a previous question as I added bad information in the middle of the night.

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim strCriteria1 As String
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long

With Me
    Select Case True
    Case ComboBoxA.value <> "": strCriteria1 = ComboBoxA.value
    'Case ComboBox1.value <> "": strCriteria1 = ComboBox1.value
    'Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
End With

With Sheets("Carrier")
    '.ClearAllFilters
    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If ComboBoxA.value <> "" Then
    Sheets("Carrier").range.AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=ComboBoxA.value
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided an argument to `Range`.  E.g. `Sheets("Carrier").range("A1").AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=ComboBoxA.value`

Comment: Sheets("Carrier").range("A1:S20000").AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:=ComboBoxA.value

Comment: I have added that range in but now it runs without stopping, but it does filter as expected.